# Why did Curtis Chen try to do this in Continuum?

Tags: plot-explanation, continuum

In the season 2 finale of the Canadian science fiction show *Continuum*, Alec Sadler goes back in time, which leads to the creation of a new Green Timeline and the subsequent destruction of the original Red Timeline.

In the season 3 premiere, Red Kiera travels from the Red Timeline to the Green Timeline right before the Red Timeline is destroyed, and she finds that her counterpart, Green Kiera, has been murdered. She eventually figures out what happened to Green Kiera: Curtis Chen shot her and failed to kill her, and then Brad Tonkin shot her and killed her.

Brad Tonkin's motivations are clear enough: he was sent by future Kellogg's militia in order to avert the wartorn dystopian future that's there in the Green Timeline. But my question is:

**Why does Curtis Chen try to kill Green Kiera?**

For those who don't remember, Curtis Chen is a member of the terrorist group Liber8 who traveled to the past, although he's secretly a mole working for the Freelancers.  Yet we know his attempt to kill Green Kiera wasn't sanctioned by the Freelancers, since when they find out they lock him up (although he escapes).

So I assume this was part of his work for the Traveler, whom we see him working for later. But why would the Traveler want Green Kiera dead?  And how exactly did Curtis and Brad Tonkin team up?